# What points to keep in mind while coding a MVC 3 project for easy upgrade to MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We are starting a new project, but we don't want to use beta software.  At the same time, we can not wait for MVC 4 release.

Comment: Why not use the beta version? If it's not a something that is going to be released in the near future, then there will most likely be a non-beta release out by the time you're done anyways.

Comment: It is our company policy not to use any beta products.

Comment: Fair enough! Check the ASP.NET MVC 4 RoadMap http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap it might give you an idea on what you are missing out on. I don't think you need to make any special considerations. It's very easy to go from MVC 3 to MVC 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the application you are developing support multiple devices (mobile, tablet, and PC)?  If it will support multiple devices then there are some considerations on how you structure your project and naming conventions used to switch to device specific controllers and views. Checkout this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features) for an explanation of the changes. Also if your application will have some REST web services or API's then you will want to look at the [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), which is part of MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from MVC3 to MVC4 is pretty easy. Here are the specific notes from Microsoft: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

I just upgraded a big MVC3 application to MVC4. We did the option of creating a new project, 10 minutes total and everything from MVC3 worked fine.

What you miss out on is developing the new features from the start (since it's a new project). But given your constraint this should be acceptable.

Also to note: MVC4 comes with a "go-live" license (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx) so you could use it in production today.